# convert normal window to modal window?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

Is there any way to convert normal window to modal window?

I have a grid with a image column.
As I click the image a window is appearing with the image.(using javascript window.open(...) )

But, as I click a different image in the grid a second window is appearing with respective image.
I dont want the user to be able to do anything else before closing the current window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

**[window.showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.showModalDialog)**

> Creates and displays a modal dialog
>   box containing a specified HTML
>   document.

Syntax

```
returnVal = window.showModalDialog(uri[, arguments][, options]);
```

> returnVal is a variant, indicating the
>   returnValue property as set by the
>   window of the document specified by
>   uri.
>
> uri is the URI of the document to
>   display in the dialog box.
>
> arguments is an optional variant that
>   contains values that should be passed
>   to the dialog box
>
> options an optional string that
>   specifies window ornamentation for the
>   dialog box, using one or more
>   semicolon delimited values

Answer (score 0):

Because it's pretty complicated to achieve that behavior to work cross-browser, I'd go for a JavaScript code that generates a similar behavior with div elements.

You can use 3rd party components for that (like [DevExpress' AspxPopupControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Popup/index.xml)) or free open-source components like [JQuery UI dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).